# How to edit the recorded macro program so that it recognizes and takes until the last value whenever I change the imported input file?

Tags: excel, excel-2003, vba

I have recorded a macro for a workbook with 7 sheets in it. Two sheets import the data from many text files and arrange them sequentially. The other sheets use this data and some other formula given and produce charts with polynomial equations. So the macro program is quite large. I have data that looks like this

```
      A   B   C   D   E
R8    0   #   *   @   $
R9   0.05 #   *   @   $
R10  0.1  #   *   @   $
.     .   .   .   .   .
.     .   .   .   .   .
.     .   .   .   .   .
R108 5.0  #   *   @   $
```

In the above data:
column A & B from row8 to 108 are imported data
C,D & E are given by formula.

My problem is that I don't have the same data in column A (0~5) which I import.

The data keeps on changing like 0~12, 0~16 & 0~40. So the final row number also changes every time. Hence I need to record macro for all the other data each time when the data changes.

Can I edit the macro I have recorded in such a way that it doesn't stop at row 108(or 5.0), but make it stop at the last value given as input (say 'R88' or 40.0 or 'R168' or 16.0 etc.)?

Also the formula given in C,D & E given in row 8 should be made to extend till the last row given as input.

For example, say I import the text file having values from 0~40 or 0~16 in columns A & B in sheet2. Now I want these values in row 8 of sheet 1, column A & B and also the corresponding formulae given in columns C,D & E should extend till row 88 or row 168. The values in sheet 1 must change as the changes occur in the imported text file irrespective of number of rows or the increasing step value.

```
       A   B   C   D   E                    A   B   C   D   E
R8     0   #   *   @   $             R8     0   #   *   @   $
R9    0.2  #   *   @   $             R9    0.25 #   *   @   $
R10   0.4  #   *   @   $             R10   0.5  #   *   @   $
.      .   .   .   .   .             .      .   .   .   .   .
.      .   .   .   .   .             .      .   .   .   .   .
.      .   .   .   .   .             .      .   .   .   .   .
R88  16.0  #   *   @   $             R168  40.0  #   *   @   $
```

Please help me out to solve this problem..

Comment: Have a look at UsedRange http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb221970(v=office.12).aspx

Answer (score 2):

If your data **starts** in the same cell on every sheet, then you can use some of the basic Excel selection commands to get all of the data.

```
'Set up a range object.
Dim rng As Range
'Select the first cell in which data is going to be.  This example uses cell "A1".
Range("A1").Select
'The following line is equivalent to pressing Shift-End-DownArrow, which selects
'everything in the current column until an empty cell is encountered.
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
'The following line is equivalent to pressing Shift-End-RightArrow, which selects
'everything in the current row until an empty cell is encountered.
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
'This selection is then a range containing all the continuous entries starting at cell A1.
'Set the Range variable to the current selection.
Set rng = Selection
```

It's important to use the `Set` keyword in VBA when assigning values to object variables.

After you paste this data to your destination, you can use similar methods to get the range it occupies, and use the following functions to determine where you should copy your formulas.

`Range.Column` returns the first column number in a range.
`Range.Columns.Count` returns the number of columns in the specified range.
`Range.Row` returns the first row in a range.
`Range.Rows.Count` returns the number of rows in a range.
In all of the above functions, you would replace `Range` with your actual range object.

Answer (score 0):

If the code that compiles the data from text files is efficient, that is, the worksheet starts in cell A1, skips no rows or columns, and has no stray non-blank cells outside the expected data range, the easiest way is:

```
Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
```

alternatively

```
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
```

To specify the range from cell C8 to the end, for filling down the formulas:

```
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
  Set rng = .Offset(7, 2).Resize(.Rows.Count - 7, 3)
End With
```

If the formulas are already present in cells C8:E8, then this

```
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
  .Offset(7, 2).Resize(.Rows.Count - 7, 3).FillDown
End With
```